# Oracle Unique Constraint Throwing Exception when rows do not exist

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have a table in an oracle database, lets call it Task, where I'm inserting a bunch of rows from a batch process.

I have a unique constraint set up on 4 columns, one of which is nullable (locationId, shelfId, itemId, and batchId), with one of the columns being nullable (shelfId)

In the process that's parsing the CSV file's values (read from another database table), they are batched in groups of 100 and posted to an API for further parsing (into the format of the above mentioned table) and inserted for later submission to another table (in a different schema, but with the same unique constraint). The issue I'm running into is where there are duplicates based on the above constraint in the file (they are typically sequential, and I have only ever seen one additional entry in the file). **After they have been parsed, they are inserted, and I'm seeing the unique constraint exception being thrown on rows that a) *do not* have a row in the table and b) *do not* meet the unique constraint. When I remove the duplicates from the initial import file I do not get any unique constraint exceptions (which... makes sense weirdly enough).**

I'm using Entity Framework in .net for the Oracle database, which I wouldn't think has anything to do with this, but it may, judging by the weirdness of this issue. I'm completely stumped as to what to do, I've tried writing additional validation and looking up the records in the table before inserting them, removing them from the initial file (which works as a work around), but I'm unsure of what to do for a long-term solution.

Example Data:

```
LocationId ShelfId ItemID  BatchId 
1          NULL    00AXXFD 1 
1          NULL    00AXXFD 1 
1          NULL    00FFD12 1 
etc...
```

Comment: Even if you have a nullable in a uniqueconstraint, that still means you can only have 1 null value in the column. Can you show us an example dataset? Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: ```
LocationId     ShelfId    ItemID     BatchId 
1                    NULL     00AXXFD 1
1                    NULL     00AXXFD 1
1                    NULL     00FFD12  1
etc...
```

The issue I'm seeing is the third row will also be seen as a duplicate, and throw the exception. The first row of the dataset is also not being inserted and throwing an exception. I've shown this to several coworkers and they're also baffled by it. I'm beginning to suspect it's a race condition somewhere or there's another version of the service being run in the environment I'm using, but it's very weird.

Comment: Adding data to question because I didnt think about there not being formatting to comments... haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting UK error because your input data contains duplicates. When you insert all of them at once they are part of the same transaction so Oracle sees duplicates and throws exception even before you commit. After it fails the transaction rolls back so you don't see any records inserted hence no duplicates found.

The correct approach is to remove duplicates from the input data (as you are doing) before inserting. 
You use Oracle to enforce UK by committing after insertion of each row.

Note - As I was saying you mayn't be committing after inserting each row. It doesn't matter if insertion happens one by one or all at once, what matters is the transaction scope. JDBC has autocommit=true/false to enable single operation commit. When it is 'true' a transaction is committed after every operation. In general it needs to be 'false' so that you can control the transaction scope

Comment: The record inserts are being done individually (using a repository model, and each call to the "insert" method calls SaveChanges(), so I wouldn't think that would be an issue? Although it's not an async call...  But wouldn't that commit each row when it's inserted?

Comment: As I was saying you mayn't be committing after inserting each row. It doesn't matter if insertion happens one by one or all at once, what matters is the transaction scope.

Comment: Ahhhhh ok. Yes that makes a lot more sense now (the Insert method accepts a list for the records being inserted parameter, which made me assume that the transaction scope was just for that operation). I've updated the way I'm calling it and it appears to be inserting the records appropriately now. Thank you!

Comment: JDBC has autocommit=true/false to enable single operation commit. When it is 'true' a transaction is committed after every operation. In general it needs to be 'false' so that you can control the transaction scope.

Comment: I can't seem to find an autocommit configuration in the configuration for the dotnet , is that configured on the database server, or at the request/application level?

Comment: at the application level on the connection object. I know JDBC does that way and pretty sure it will be working similarly on .net

Comment: Ah it seems you have to wrap it in a transaction manually to allow this. I've figured out a different workaround though.